# Why I can not do recursive commits to subversion with monodevelop?

Tags: svn, monodevelop

At some point, I don't remember exactly when, MonoDevelop stopped being able to commit several folders recursively into my subversion repository. I have to do separate commits for each separate folder. I have version 2.8.8.4 of MonoDevelop running on a Mac and version 1.6 of subversion. Any ideas? It is very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

How does it break? Can you please [file a bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com) with more information?

Comment: It doesn't really break. When I choose Version Control > Commit on the context menu, the only files that are shown with changes are those on that folder level. To get to the files on a subfolder I have to the extra select it.